# C++ How to show array element memory address in decimal (instead of hexadecimal)?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

My program

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

        int a[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                int address = &a[i];
                cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << " at address " << &a[i] << " = decimal " << address << endl;
        }

}
```

I want to print array element address in decimal, but above code fails to compile.

I have also tried to print it using

```
cout << std::dec << &a[i] << endl;
```

but that does not work too

---

### Answer: Figured it out from

[Converting a pointer into an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153065/converting-a-pointer-into-an-integer)

Have to cast the address to `reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>`

```
 cout << "a[" << i << "] = " << a[i] << " at address " << &a[i] << " = " << reinterpret_cast<std::uintptr_t>(&a[i]) << endl;
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the address value can fit into an `int` type. There is a `std::uintptr_t` type that should be used instead, however, the standard does not mandate implementations to have that type

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/153065/315052

Comment: This should do it: `auto address = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(&a[i]);`. But check the related questions, too.