# Which integer type can be safely and portably used to always hold a pointer value

Tags: c++

Which integer type can be safely be used to always hold a pointer value? Would it be `std::intptr_t`?  But I thought `int` would also always hold a pointer value and is present in every build, and stuff like `int32_t` or `int64_t` would be changed if the input size is not exact

Comment: Why? Use a `void *`.

Comment: If you want to use an integer type, `size_t` is the best bet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a pointer into an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153065/608639), [What is uintptr_t data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1845482/608639), [unsigned int vs. size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/q/131803/608639), etc.

Comment: Also be careful of old memory models, like x86 segmented addresses. If I recall, `size_t` and pointers are different sizes (this is a almost never a problem in practice).

Answer (score 5):

> Which integer type can be safely and portably used to always hold a pointer value:
>
> Would it be std::intptr_t?

The entire idea of storing a pointer value in an integer is not necessarily fully portable to all systems.

`std::intptr_t` is the most appropriate choice on systems where it is provided. And correspondingly, `std::uintptr_t`.

> But I thought int would also always hold a pointer value

You were mistaken. `int` is not guaranteed to always be able to represent all pointer values. In fact, on the [most common 64 bit systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) - where pointers are 64 bit - `int` is 32 bits.

For reasoning *why* that is, here is a document outlining the reasons in the case of UNIX/POSIX: http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html

---

You should also consider *why* you would want to do such thing in the first place. I can think of a few reasons:

1. In order to calculate the alignment of the address. This should be no longer necessary since C++11 which has `std::align`.
2. In order to further convert the integer into a string for debugging purposes. The standard library already has ways of converting a pointer to a string (`std::printf` family of functions and character streams). But those are not available in all contexts (signal handlers; freestanding implementations), and the pointer to integer conversion might therefore make sense in those contexts.
3. Calculating a hash. `std::hash` (C++11) already has a specialisation for pointers, but if you find your standard library implementation insufficient, you could use a custom hash function after converting to integer.
4. Storing data in "unused" bits of a pointer. This optimisation technique is highly implementation dependent. Low order bits of pointers with alignment greater than 1 can be used. 16 high order bits can be used in x86-64 architecture (which may shrink to [possibly to 7] in future: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/2b/80/5-level_paging_white_paper.pdf).

Comment: Except that `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are optional in the standard. For some architectures, it might not be possible to represent an address with an integer of supported size. So not 100% portable, but at least they will either work as expected, or fail to compile.

Comment: @aschepler I incorporated some of your points into my answer. Out of curiosity, do you know of any such architecture, which also has a C++ compiler?

Comment: I don't know of one.

Comment: I've been collecting a [list of platforms](https://github.com/o11c/targets) - in all my data, char/short/int/long/long-long/ptr is are always 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits (although there is sometimes padding for pointers). Note that there *may* be more than kind of pointer (like `near` vs `far`), and the non-default ones may or may not be backed by int24_t or similar types that don't exist in standard C.

Comment: @eerorika I know one use of integers to store pointers: save space. There are huge structures such as [Binary Decision Diagram (BDD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram). The least significant bit of each child tells if the child is negated or not, while all other bits contain the address of the child. With BDDs it is not uncommon to run out of RAM, so every bit counts.

Comment: @eerorika you save space for the flags. The flags are stored at the LSB or-ed with the address. The address must be aligned, so the lsb is zeroed before dereferencing

Comment: @MichaelVeksler yeah. It took me a while to get what you wrote. I'm adding a generic version to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, std::intptr_t is a better option. It is defined to different width to save address as a pointer on x64 or x86 system.

```
// Definitions of common types
#ifdef _WIN64
    typedef unsigned __int64 size_t;
    typedef __int64          ptrdiff_t;
    typedef __int64          intptr_t;
#else
    typedef unsigned int     size_t;
    typedef int              ptrdiff_t;
    typedef int              intptr_t;
#endif
```

Comment: But it isn't defined in such a way as to guarantee what the OP wants.