# Where is <inttypes.h> in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, c99

I'd like to use the C99 header file inttypes.h in a Visual Studio project (I'd like to printf 64 bit numbers).

However, this file does not seem to exist in my install.

Is this just not part of VS2005? Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio

Comment: @Mike, that Q is about `stdint.h`, they're different

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's at [google](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/). VS doesn't come with `<inttypes.h>`

Comment: Then they should stick to the C++ standards.

Comment: Um, `<inttypes.h>` is a C99 header, isn't it?

Comment: @sbi: Yes, it is a C99 header, but Visual Studio doesn't support C99 in versions prior to Visual Studio 2013 (though even 2013 doesn't have full C99 support).

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not included in VS 2005.

An alternative is Boost's implementation in the [Boost::Integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/integer/index.html) library, specifically [boost/cstdint.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/integer/cstdint.htm)

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2005 see the bug "C99 header `<inttypes.h>` missing" at http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/99133/c99-header-inttypes-h-missing#details where it seems Microsoft did not plan to add the file to Visual Studio 2005.

It seems to me that `inttypes.h` is missing also from Visual Studio 2010.

For the C++ header `<cinttypes>` in Visual Studio 2012 see the bug "C++11 header  is missing (Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 RC 11.0.50522.1)" at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/748766/c-11-header-cinttypes-is-missing-microsoft-visual-studio-ultimate-2012-rc-11-0-50522-1