# Size of int in C on different architectures

Tags: c, cross-platform, types, integer

I am aware that the specification of the C language does not dictate the exact size of each integer type (e.g., `int`).

What I am wondering is: Is there a way in C (not C++) to define an integer type with a specific size that ensures it will be the same across different architectures? Like:

```
typedef int8 <an integer with 8 bits>
typedef int16 <an integer with 16 bits>
```

Or any other way that will allow other parts of the program to be compiled on different architecture.

Comment: Your question is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio

Comment: @zilgo: The answer may be similar; the question is not. In 126279, the OP is already aware of stdint.h; NawaMan (apparently) wasn't when asking the question.

Comment: Note that your last assumption is wrong. Differences in the size of an int do not necessarily block compilation on other architectures, but latent assumptions like `i == i & 0xFFFFFFFF` may. A good programmer writes `& 0xFFFF` when he wants math modulo 2^16, and doesn't care whether `unsigned short` has precisely 16 bits.

Comment: MSalters: Absolutely.  I do not understand why so many people seem to have a burning desire for fixed width sizes - in 99% of cases, *minimum* width sizes are all you need.

Comment: I am packing different data into array of char (or point of char) so I need to deal with the size.

Comment: i know this question is old, but aren't data types like WORD, DOUBLEWORD etc. usually of fixed size no matter the architecture?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want is `<stdint.h>`, which compilers that conform to the C standard ("C99") will implement. Unfortunately, this does not include Microsoft. Fortunately, an open-source project provides a `<stdint.h>` for Windows, see [msinttypes](http://code.google.com/p/msinttypes/).

This will allow you to use `int32_t` and `uint32_t`, plus 8, 16, and 64, and many others.

Note: the header file itself is not optional in the standard, however, most of the types in the header are individually optional. Some are not. The most commonly used types are the optional ones, but nothing stops you from using the required ones. The thing is, if an implementation provides the header at all, in practice they define all of the types.

Comment: Does this means that if I always compile my code with C99 compiler and always include <stdint.h>, I should be sure that int32_t is always 4 bytes?

Comment: @NawaMan - you can be sure that `int32_t` will have exactly 32-bits. If the platform doesn't have a 32-bit int type, the compile will fail as the `int32_t` type won't be defined. Also, many non-C99 compilers provide a `stdint.h` - for those that don't (Microsoft) you can get one from several place pointed to in other comments/answers including: http://snipplr.com/view/18199/stdinth/

Comment: @NawaMan: YES. It should also be noted that C99 gives you minimums for the classical types: int >= 16, long >= 32, long long >= 64.

Answer (score 13):

C99, in [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h), defines types like `int8_t` and `int16_t`.

Comment: I believe there is a version that covers many other platforms that don't conform to C99 as well, but I'm not sure.

Comment: MSVC doesn't like `<stdint.h>`. Not that I care, I stopped using it because of the horrible code-gen.

Comment: That's interesting. Are you saying it doesn't have stdint.h or cstdint or that it doesn't have int16_t even though it supports a type with that bit width? That would, I think, make it non-conforming, and I doubt MS would be that stupid.

Comment: I tried a few combinations of #include-ing stdint or cstdint but suprisingly VC9 could not find anything like that. Searching fo "stdint" in MSDN confirms that it's not there.

Comment: A public domain (not even a MIT/BSD license - you don't even need to keepa copyright attribution around) stdint.h for MSVC (a slightly modified version from MinGW): http://snipplr.com/view/18199/stdinth/

Comment: @paxdiablo - `int8_t` and `int16_t` are optional, but only if the implementation doesn't actually have integer types with those widths.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I agree with Michael Burr; stdint.h itself is not optional.

Comment: @paxdiablo: VC simply isn't C99 conform. (They don't even claim to be.) See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156267/ for `stdint.h` on VC.

Answer (score 5):

No, the C standard specifies minimum sizes for integral types but makes no guarantee on maximum sizes.

An implementation shall provide `intN_t` types if types of that size are available. I only mention that since you had a cross-platform tag - an implementation that does not have a type of the correct bit width does not need to provide those types.

You can generally select (with setting defines with, for example, `cc -D_INT16_IS_INT` and `#ifdef`s) the correct type to use for a specific bit size. You can work out the required defines for each platform you want to support with C code using `CHAR_BIT` and `sizeof()`.

The relevant section of the c1x draft (n1362) is:

---

*7.18.1.1 Exact-width integer types*

1. The typedef name `intN_t` designates a signed integer type with width `N`, no padding bits, and a two’s complement representation. Thus, `int8_t` denotes a signed integer type with a width of exactly 8 bits.
2. The typedef name `uintN_t` designates an unsigned integer type with width `N`. Thus, `uint24_t` denotes an unsigned integer type with a width of exactly 24 bits.
3. These types are optional. However, if an implementation provides integer types with widths of 8, 16, 32, or 64 bits, no padding bits, and (for the signed types) that have a two’s complement representation, it shall define the corresponding typedef names.

---

Regarding the selection of types, something like this should suffice:

```
#ifdef INT32_IS_SHORT
    typedef short INT32
#endif
#ifdef INT32_IS_INT
    typedef int INT32
#endif
#ifdef INT32_IS_LONG
    typedef long INT32
#endif
```

Comment: If you want to fail when the system doesn't have the exact size, then just use `int8_t` or `int16_t` - the build will fail if the system doesn't have them - no need for the conditional code. If you want to not fail but use the next best type instead, use int_least8_t or int_least16_t.

Comment: The preprocessor can't evaluate `sizeof()`.

Comment: According to the C99 standard, long has to be more than 16-bits ;)

Comment: Good point, Joe, fixed, even though I noticed the smiley :-) Michael, OP wanted the "program to be compiled on different architecture" so failing to compile probably isn't quite good enough, and they wanted "specific size" so next best type is probably not desired either.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you check for each platform with `#ifdef` or so, I doubt it's easily possible. But many libraries already do that task for you. For MSVC it's [`__int8`, `__int16`, &c.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx) The GTK library has similar typedefs.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the answer is no. We code for different platforms and we just use typedefs for the specific platforms using #if/#else. For example on Win32: typedef int int32;

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at [pstdint.h](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h). It is a portable implementation of stdint.h, and does not require C99 compiler support.

Answer (score 0):

You could always write an arithmetic library that used vectors of unsigned char for the numbers. That way you could use numbers of whatever bit length you want, and even allow the bit length to vary.

Actually, you don't need to implement such a library because GNU MP handles this already.

http://gmplib.org/