# Size of data types does vary depending upon OS or platform?

Tags: c, operating-system, size

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [size of a datatype in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686655/size-of-a-datatype-in-c)

I want to ask you does size of any data types does vary on different os or platform.?
like 32-bit system 64 bit system.?
Question is more for c language programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They can yes (and they often do). The C standard requires certain minimal ranges for integer and floating point types, but leaves a lot of freedom to the platform to decide the actual sizes of the types.

See eg. [`limits.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits.h) and [`float.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Float.h).

Furthermore, there is a strict relation between the sizes of integer types that needs to be true :

```
sizeof(char) == 1
sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long) <= sizeof(long long)
```

Platforms will usually pick sizes that are natural to the hardware. For example, `int`s will usually have the native word size (32 bits on 32bit hardware eg.).

For floating point types, there is less variation. Most platforms are more or less compliant with [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

Comment: Correction: `long` and `long long` can be the same size (if `long` is 64 bits).  And strictly speaking, the requirements are on the *ranges* of the types, not their sizes; a sufficiently insane system could have int bigger than long if int has more padding bits than long.

Comment: @Keith : I fixed that typo - thanks ! About the insane systems, as you call them, that's a point well taken, but I hope it's an academic point, and I'll never see it in reality (I never have so far).

Answer (score 2):

Sure. This is implicit in your question on a 32 bit system pointers are 32 bit that is usually 4 byte, on 64bit system 8 byte.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I guess that is why Jens used "usually".