# Does size of int variable depend on architecture or compiler?

Tags: c

For example, I have an processor with 64-bit registers.
Can it be 2 different compilers: one with size of int equals 32-bit and another with size of int equals 16-bit?

Comment: Short answer: yes.

See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438794/is-the-size-of-c-int-2-bytes-or-4-bytes

Comment: It is the compiler that decides how big an int is.  If you can run a 16 bit compiler on a 64 bit system, your ints will be 16 bits.

Comment: It depends on whatever the compiler writer thought was a good choice.  It used to be automatic and match the processor's register size.  That's over and done with, memory is the constraint today.  Lots of 64-bit compilers will use a 32-bit int.

Comment: @HansPassant: Another rationale for making `int` 32 bits is that it allows 8, 16, 32, and 64 bits to be covered by the predefined types. If `char` is 8 bits and `int` is 64 bits, then `short` is (probably) either 16 or 32 bits, and the other size isn't covered. (Extended integer types are an option, though.)

Answer (score 2):

The size of int variable or any datatype's variable depends on the compiler. The compilers vendors decisions may be influenced by the current architectures. you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686655/size-of-a-datatype-in-c) discussion to get more detail.