# C++: Datatypes, which to use and when?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

I've been told that I should use `size_t` always when I want 32bit `unsigned int`, I don't quite understand why, but I think it has something to do with that if someone compiles the program on 16 or 64 bit machines, the `unsigned int` would become 16 or 64 bit but `size_t` won't, but why doesn't it? and how can I force the bit sizes to exactly what I want?

So, where is the list of which datatype to use and when? for example, is there a `size_t` alternative to `unsigned short`? or for 32bit `int`? etc. How can I be sure my datatypes have as many bits as I chose at the first place and not need to worry about different bit sizes on other machines?

Mostly I care more about the memory used rather than the marginal speed boost I get from doubling the memory usage, since I have not much RAM. So I want to stop worrying will everything break apart if my program is compiled on a machine that's not 32bit. For now I've used `size_t` always when i want it to be 32bit, but for `short` I don't know what to do. Someone help me to clear my head.

On the other hand: If I need 64 bit size variable, can I use it on a 32bit machine successfully? and what is that datatype name (if i want it to be 64bit always) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_t` is not always 32-bit.  E.g. It's 64-bit on 64-bit platforms.

For fixed-size integers, [stdint.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h) is best.  But it doesn't come with VS2008 or earlier - you have to [download it separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156267/where-is-inttypes-h-in-visual-studio-2005/1156285#1156285).  (It comes as a standard part of VS2010 and most other compilers).

Since you're using VS2008, you can use the MS-specific `__int32`, `unsigned __int32` etc types.  Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/29dh1w7z.aspx).

To answer the 64-bit question: Most modern compilers have a 64-bit type, even on 32-bit systems.  The compiler will do some magic to make it work.  For Microsoft compilers, you can just use the `__int64` or `unsigned __int64` types.

Comment: `size_t` existed long before 64 bits...I should know, I used it in Borland C++ compiler of late 1990's and early 2000s.

Comment: [Where is <inttypes.h> in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156267/where-is-inttypes-h-in-visual-studio-2005/1156285#1156285)

Comment: Generally, I'd suggest using the types in `<boost/cstdint.hpp>`, as they are available for VisualStudio and pretty much any other C++ compiler.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: I've changed the first paragraph to try to clarify it.  I was just using 64-bit as an example, since the question asker seems to think size_t is always 32-bit.

Answer (score 3):

`size_t` is for storing object sizes. It is of exactly the right size for that and only that purpose - 4 bytes on 32-bit systems and 8 bytes on 64-bit systems. You shouldn't confuse it with `unsigned int` or any other datatype. It might be equivalent to `unsigned int` or might be not depending on the implementation (system bitness included).

Once you need to store something other than an object size you shouldn't use `size_t` and should instead use some other datatype.

Comment: I'd also add that `size_t` is the type returned by the `sizeof` operator.  However, in practice `size_t` is not *just* strictly for storing object sizes.  For example, it is used by various standard library functions, such as `memcpy`, to store array lengths.

Comment: Eh, doesn't memcpy work on an `unsigned char[N]` ? I.e. there's no difference between array length and object size. Also, you'd often pass a `sizeof (struct T)` to `memcpy`, which makes sense only when you think of `memcpy` as taking an object size.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note: For containers, to indicate their size, don't use `size_t`, use `container<...>::size_type`

Comment: I don't think so, except perhaps for embedded systems programming. For ordinary general code it adds verbosity, reduces clarity, and gains nothing. :-)

Comment: @Alf: When writing generic code, this might be useful as you might want to include not only the standard containers but also some other STL-compatible container, for which the size_type might be unsigned short, for example. It does add verbosity, I agree, but I don't think it's a bad thing. Though obviously I should agree that I never write size_type myself. Unless in generic code

Answer (score 2):

[boost/cstdint.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/cstdint.html) can be used to be sure integers have right size.

Answer (score 2):

`size_t` is not *not* necessarily 32-bit. It has been 16-bit with some compilers. It's 64-bit on a 64-bit system.

The C++ standard guarantees, via reference down to the C standard, that `long` is at least 32 bits.

`int` is only formally guaranteed 16 bits, but in practice I wouldn't worry: the chance that any ordinary code will be used on a 16-bit system is slim indeed, and on any 32-bit system `int` is 32-bit. Of course it's different if you're coding for a 16-bit system like some embedded computer. But in that case you'd probably be writing system-specific code anyway.

Where you need exact sizes you can use `<stdint.h>` if your compiler supports that header (it was introduced in C99, and the current C++ standard stems from 1998), or alternatively the corresponding Boost library header [boost/cstdint.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/integer/doc/html/index.html).

However, in general, just use `int`. ;-)

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, one of the quirks of the nature of data types is that it depends a great deal on which compiler you're using.  Naturally, if you're only compiling for one target, there is no need to worry - just find out how large the type is using `sizeof(...)`.

If you need to cross-compile, you could ensure compatibility by defining your own `typedef`s for each target (surrounded `#ifdef` blocks, referencing which target you're cross-compiling to).

If you're ever concerned that it could be compiled on a system that uses types with even weirder sizes than you have anticipated, you could always `assert(sizeof(short)==2)` or equivalent, so that you could guarantee at runtime that you're using the correctly sized types.

Your question is tagged visual-studio-2008, so I would recommend looking in the documentation for that compiler for pre-defined data types.  Microsoft has a number that are predefined, such as `BYTE`, `DWORD`, and `LARGE_INTEGER`.

Take a look in windef.h winnt.h for more.