# What is the meaning of the format control specifier %016I64X in sprintf_s

Tags: string-formatting, printf, format-specifiers

What is the meaning of the format control specifier "%S\%016I64X%S" in this sprintf_s command ?

As far as I know, it defines a string which converts numbers to unsigned 64 bit integer in Hexadecimal format. I would like to know whether I am right ? Please help me..

```
char lFileName[MAX_PATH];
sprintf_s( lFileName, MAX_PATH, "%S\\%016I64X%S", mSavePath.GetBuffer(),aBuffer->GetTimestamp(), lExt );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, it looks like a Visual C++ usage of

```
int sprintf_s(char *buffer, size_t sizeOfBuffer, const char *format, ...);
```

The format consists  of multiple *directives*:  `"%S"`, `"\\"`, `"%016I64X"`, `"%S"`.

`"%S"`  "When used with printf functions, specifies a *wide-character* string; ..." [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx)

`"\\"` is simply a `\`.

`"%016I64X"` is an `X` format specifier of hexadecimal output. `0` to indicate zero-filling as needed.  `16` to indicate the minimum output length.  `I64` is a windows specific modifier indicating the expected integer is of windows specific type `unsigned __int64`.  [more](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx)

You are on the right track with "unsigned 64 bit integer".

Comment: Why not `%uud`? :D

Comment: @pushpen.paul Re: [Why not `%uud`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123066/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-format-control-specifier-016i64x-in-sprintf-s/18429938?noredirect=1#comment91915809_18429938): `"%uud"` is C standard `"%u"` followed by `"ud"`.  Perhaps you are thinking of `"%llu"`? IAC, an implementation type `unsigned __int64` could map to standard types `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long` or others and then use `"%llX"`, `"%lX"` to print hex.  Using C99 specifiers, like `"%" PRIX64` makes most sense via [`<inttypes.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1156285/2410359).