# Best Practices: Should I create a typedef for byte in C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, typedef

Do you prefer to see something like `t_byte*` (with `typedef unsigned char t_byte`) or `unsigned char*` in code?

I'm leaning towards `t_byte` in my own libraries, but have never worked on a large project where this approach was taken, and am wondering about pitfalls.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're using C99 or newer, you should use `stdint.h` for this.  `uint8_t`, in this case.

C++ didn't get this header until C++11, calling it `cstdint`. Old versions of Visual C++ didn't let you use C99's `stdint.h` in C++ code, but pretty much every other C++98 compiler did, so you may have that option even when using old compilers.

As with so many other things, [Boost](http://www.boost.org/) papers over this difference in [`boost/integer.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/integer/doc/html/index.html), providing things like `uint8_t` if your compiler's standard C++ library doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest that if your compiler supports it use the *C99* `<stdint.h>` header types such as `uint8_t` and `int8_t`.

If your compiler does not support it, create one. [Here's](http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h) an example for *VC++*, older versions of which do not have `stdint.h`.  *GCC* does support `stdint.h`, and indeed most of *C99*

One problem with your suggestion is that the sign of `char` is implementation defined, so if you do create a type alias. you should at least be explicit about the sign. There is some merit in the idea since in *C#* for example a `char` is 16bit. But it has a byte type as well.

---

Additional note...

There was no problem with your suggestion, you did in fact specify unsigned.

I would also suggest that plain `char` is used if the data is in fact character data, i.e. is a representation of plain text such as you might display on a console. This will present fewer type agreement problems when using standard and third-party libraries. If on the other hand the data represents a non-character entity such as a bitmap, or if it is numeric 'small integer' data upon which you might perform arithmetic manipulation, or data that you will perform logical operations on, then one of the `stdint.h` types (or even a type defined from one of them) should be used.

I recently got caught out on a *TI C54xx* compiler where `char` is in fact 16bit, so that is why using *stdint.h* where possible, even if you use it to then define a `byte` type is preferable to assuming that `unsigned char` is a suitable alias.

Comment: Good point about my example, I marked Warren's answer correct because he was first and his post was succinct. Upvoted you at least...

Answer (score 4):

I prefer for types to convey the meaning of the values stored in it. If I need a type describing a byte as it is on my machine, I very much prefer `byte_t` over `unsigned char`, which could mean just about anything. (I have been working in a code base that used either `signed char` or `unsigned char` to store UTF-8 strings.) The same goes for `uint8_t`. It could just be used as that: an 8bit unsigned integer.

With `byte_t` (as with any other aptly named type), there rarely ever is a need to look up what it is defined to (and if so, a good editor will take 3secs to look it up for you; maybe 10secs, if the code base is huge), and just by looking at it it's clear what's stored in objects of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer `boost::int8_t` and `boost::uint8_t`.

If you don't want to use boost you could borrow `boost\cstdint.hpp`.

Another option is to use [portable version of `stdint.h`](http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h) (link from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio/126285#126285) answer).

Comment: I'm not really sold on requiring a boost header just for typedefs.

Comment: Note that while stdint.h is defined by C99, there is no <cstdint> required by the current ISO C++ standard (because it predates C99), so you may find in some compilers you have to use the C convention for header names is use stdint types, and that would be the most portable form.

Answer (score 0):

Besides your awkward naming convention, I think that might be okay. Keep in mind boost does this for you, to help with cross-platform-ability:

```
#include <boost/integer.hpp>

typedef boost::uint8_t byte_t;
```

Note that usually type's are suffixed with `_t`, as in `byte_t`.

Comment: Types you define should NOT be suffixed with "_t" as such names are reserved for extensions to the language and standard libraries (e.g. so that adding uint8_t does not break lots of existing code).

Comment: @chrisharris where did you find this info? I am looking through a draft of the ISO C++ Standards and can't find that section, but I have a co-worker who likes to suffix all his class/function templates that way and would like to point it out to him.

Comment: @stinky472: I have no idea what the ISO C Standard says about this, but common sense says custom names should not collide with standard ones, so to avoid trouble it's better to use `byte`. Or, if your co-worker prefers, use a *prefix* instead of a suffix: `t_byte`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use standard types, unsigned char, uint8_t, etc., so any programmer looking at the source does not have to refer back to headers to grok the code.  The more typedefs you use the  more time it takes for others to get to know your typing conventions.  For structures, absolutely use typedefs, but for primitives use them sparingly.