# what is 1UI64 type?

Tags: c

I recently saw this 1UI64 type. I didnt get what kind of type is it. How can they use 1 before ?

Comment: which compiler provides this extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a **type**, it's a 64-bit **constant** integer of value 1.

Answer (score 5):

In Microsoft C/C++ The `I64` part of the expression is a suffix for integer constants that indicates the constant should be a 64-bit type:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2xf226.aspx

This is a Microsoft extension, even though the docs don't call that out.

A somewhat more portable way to specify such a constant might be to include `<stdint.h>` and use `UINT64_C(1)` - MSVC has `stdint.h` as of VS2010.

For versions prior to that you might consider the options provided in this SO question: [C99 stdint.h header and MS Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio)

Comment: you could also mention the C99 version `UINT64_C(1)` from `stdint.h`

Comment: @Christoph: Done. I had a mention about `UINT64_C()` in my answer at first, but decided to leave it out since MSVC complicates the `stdint.h` situation a little.  But since you suggested it, I added it back with a bit of detail.

Answer (score 4):

That's an unsigned 64-bit 1.

Answer (score 2):

Probably nonstandard Unsigned Integer 64-bit, or a fixed point 0.64 format.