# What type for operations on pointers

Tags: c++, c, pointers

I've searched quite a bit, but couldn't find anything helpful - but then I'm not sure I'm searching for the right thing.

Is there any scalar defined by the standard that has to be at least as large as a pointer? I.e. sizeof(?) >= sizeof(void*).

I need it because I'm writing a small garbage collector and want something along the lines of this:

```
struct Tag {
    uint32_t desc:sizeof(uint32_t)*8-2; // pointer to typedescriptor
    uint32_t free:1;
    uint32_t mark:1;
};
```

I'd prefer something that's valid according to the standard (if we're at it, I was quite surprised that sizeof(uint32_t)*8-2 is valid for the bitfield definition - but VS2010 allows it).

So does size_t fulfill this requirement?

Edit: So after my inclusion of both C and C++ lead to some problems (well and there I thought they would be similar in that regard), I'd actually settle for one of them (I don't really need C++ for this part of the code and I can link C and c++ together so that should work). And C99 seems to be the right standard in this case from the answers.

Comment: C or C++? Could you choose one, or do you want an answer for both?

Comment: Why not just `struct Tag { void* desc; int free:1; int mark:1; };`?

Comment: @aschepler: Presumably an attempt to minimise memory footprint.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it seems that void * will do it.

Comment: You need `#include <limits.h>` and `CHAR_BIT` instead of `8`. The type `uint32_t` is not guaranteed to be defined in all C99 implementations. `#include <stdint.h>` (you already have for this snippet) and use `uint_least32_t` instead

Comment: @aschepler: Since structs are usually word size aligned for performance reasons, that would use 8byte instead of 4 on a 32bit machine and 16 instead of 8 on 64bit. Since the Tag is needed for every allocated objected (and every entry in the free list) that's some easily reduced overhead (and has only a small performance hit when the GC runs)

Comment: @pmg: Just used uint32_t for the fast example, but good to know anyhow. Also interesting that there's a CHAR_BIT definition, I thought one of the only things defined in C (and therefore hopefully in c++ as well) was that a char is always one byte.

Comment: `char` and `byte`, in C, are synonyms. What the Standard does not specify is the number of bits in them: it mandates **8 or more** bits in a byte though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could include `<stdint.h>` (or `<cstdint>`) and use [`uintptr_t` or `intptr_t`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#Integers_wide_enough_to_hold_pointers).

Since MSVC refuses to support C99, you may need to include `<Windows.h>` and use [ULONG_PTR or LONG_PTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751.aspx) instead. (See [C99 stdint.h header and MS Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio))

(Also, please use [CHAR_BIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200954/what-is-char-bit) instead of 8.)

Comment: That's not portable though is it?

Comment: @David: It's part of C99, though I think the header is `<inttypes.h>`

Comment: @John I thought it was optional. Also not in C++. And only optional in C++11? Or has that changed recently?

Comment: `[u]intptr_t` types are optional

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, great. And I think optional C99 should be good enough - at least I'd get a fast error if I used it somewhere where it wouldn't work.

Comment: under MSVC you want `INT_PTR` or `UINT_PTR`

Comment: @David I don't know if it's part of any C++ standard.  The OP would need to clarify his needs, since he tagged it both `C` and `C++`.

Comment: It is optional because the language standard(s) can't require an int type big enough to hold a pointer. Could be a problem on systems with a segmented memory architecture.

Comment: I gave a +1, although I'm not convinced that `CHAR_BIT` is needed when talking about how many bits to a byte.  Sure, DEC had 12-bit bytes, and even today you'll see standards refer to octets.  But, really, we aren't about to see the resurgence of nonstandard bytes.

Comment: @Max: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098149/what-platforms-have-something-other-than-8-bit-char. Really it depends what the code is for - most apps are never going to run on a DSP, or for that matter any "embedded" target, but general utility code might. Making the assumption simply because `8` is faster to type than `CHAR_BIT` is what Larry Wall would call "false laziness". Making it because you're doing I/O where bytes really need to be octets is fine, it's easy enough to document and/or check at compile-time.

Comment: @Max: Well I suggested `CHAR_BIT` because I initially mistaken OP wants a bit field with `8*sizeof(void*)-2` bytes :). With `CHAR_BIT` it is clear with that 8 is for. And it isn't a bad thing to make it more portable, right? ;)

Comment: Well I just didn't know that C allowed anything but 8bit/byte in the first post (and that although I've read Knuth and he discusses that in the beginning of book1~), I'm always thankful for more tips - sure the code won't run anywhere where it'd matter, but hey, it can't harm. And considering that a pointer is really sizeof(void*) * CHAR_BIT long, using CHAR_BIT is really the correct solution I'd think.

Comment: `intptr_t` works just fine in Visual Studio 2010. What version are you using?

Comment: OK, I'm convinced you need the documentation properties of a constant.  If I see the magic number 8, I might think of several things that are 8-somethings, and bits-in-a-byte is only one of those.

Answer (score 1):

C99 has the optional `uintptr_t` in `<stdint.h>`which guarantees that you can convert between a uintptr_t and a pointer value, though it doesn't say anything about any operations on integer.

Generally, on common platforms a void* is the same as any other pointer and  converting a pointer to an integer, manipulating that integer and converting it back to a pointer yields well defined resultes, but C does not guarantee this so you'll have to know the compilers/platform you want to target.

Best you probably can do is use the above mentioned uintptr_t if you have a C99 compiler, or compile a program on the target platform which  checks whether sizeof(void*) is equal to any of the sizeof unsigned short,int,long,long long and generate a header file where you typedef your own uintptr according to what the program found out.