# INT_FAST16_MAX does not reflect type size in MSVC 2010?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, c99, stdint

C99 defines `int_fast16_t` as an "*integer types being usually fastest having at least the specified width*", and Microsoft define it as a 32-bit integer in MSVC 2010:

```
typedef char int_fast8_t;
typedef int int_fast16_t;
typedef int int_fast32_t;

typedef unsigned char uint_fast8_t;
typedef unsigned int uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned int uint_fast32_t;
```

Yet, Microsoft have set the limits to not reflect the actual underlying data type:

```
#define INT_FAST8_MIN       (-0x7f - _C2)
#define INT_FAST16_MIN      (-0x7fff - _C2)
#define INT_FAST32_MIN      (-0x7fffffff - _C2)

#define INT_FAST8_MAX       0x7f
#define INT_FAST16_MAX      0x7fff
#define INT_FAST32_MAX      0x7fffffff
#define UINT_FAST8_MAX      0xff
#define UINT_FAST16_MAX     0xffff
#define UINT_FAST32_MAX     0xffffffff
```

One would assume that the intent of the standard would be to look like this:

```
#define INT_FAST16_MIN      (-0x7fffffff - _C2)
#define INT_FAST16_MAX      0x7fffffff
#define UINT_FAST16_MAX     0xffffffff
```

Otherwise this makes the constants completely redundant?

**Edit:** Example of NetBSD setting as expected:

```
/* Maximum values of fastest minimum-width signed integer types. */
#define INT_FAST8_MAX   INT32_MAX
#define INT_FAST16_MAX  INT32_MAX
#define INT_FAST32_MAX  INT32_MAX
#define INT_FAST64_MAX  INT64_MAX
```

http://fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/arm/include/_stdint.h?im=3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug. MSVC is a C++ compiler and Microsoft has never focused on supporting newer C standards. VS 2010 is [the first MSVC version that has `<stdint.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126279/995714) so unsurprisingly there'd be many issues.

Herb Sutter, a software architect at Microsoft, and chair of the ISO C++ standards committee, has written that

> ## 1. Our primary goal is to support "most of C99/C11 that is a subset of ISO C++98/C++11."
>
> VC++ 2010 already fully supports the C subset of C++98, including things like `<stdint.h>` and declarations in the middle of a block.[*] The C subset of C++98 is approximately C95 (with very few incompatibilities with C95; i.e., there are very few cases where legal C95 code has a different meaning or is invalid in C++98) plus a few C99 features like declaring variables in the middle of blocks).
>
> [Reader Q&A: What about VC++ and C99?](https://herbsutter.com/2012/05/03/reader-qa-what-about-vc-and-c99/)

But the first version that actually supports *some* C99 features is [VS 2013](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/06/c99-acknowledged-at-last-as-microsoft-lays-out-its-path-to-c14/) with more features introduced in VS2015

> C99 Conformance Visual Studio 2015 fully implements the C99 Standard Library, with the exception of any library features that depend on compiler features not yet supported by the Visual C++ compiler (for example,  is not implemented).
>
> [What's New for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh409293(v=vs.140))

But even nowadays [VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615184/995714) and [VS 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57965155/995714) still don't support all features of C99/C11

> The compiler’s support for C99 Preprocessor rules is incomplete in Visual Studio 2017. We're overhauling the preprocessor, and began shipping those changes in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8 with the /experimental:preprocessor compiler switch.
>
> [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019)

---

I couldn't install VS2010 but I checked with VS 2012 and see that the definitions in stdint.h was fixed. Here's the relevant part in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\stdint.h`

```
...
typedef signed char        int_fast8_t;
typedef int                int_fast16_t;
typedef int                int_fast32_t;
typedef long long          int_fast64_t;
typedef unsigned char      uint_fast8_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint_fast16_t;
typedef unsigned int       uint_fast32_t;
typedef unsigned long long uint_fast64_t;
...
#define INT_FAST8_MIN    INT8_MIN
#define INT_FAST16_MIN   INT32_MIN
#define INT_FAST32_MIN   INT32_MIN
#define INT_FAST64_MIN   INT64_MIN
#define INT_FAST8_MAX    INT8_MAX
#define INT_FAST16_MAX   INT32_MAX
#define INT_FAST32_MAX   INT32_MAX
#define INT_FAST64_MAX   INT64_MAX
#define UINT_FAST8_MAX   UINT8_MAX
#define UINT_FAST16_MAX  UINT32_MAX
#define UINT_FAST32_MAX  UINT32_MAX
#define UINT_FAST64_MAX  UINT64_MAX
...
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1992-2012 by P.J. Plauger.  ALL RIGHTS RESERVED.
 * Consult your license regarding permissions and restrictions.
V6.00:0009 */
```

The header in VS 2013 is the same