# Learning C, my compiler already knows bool (Visual Studio 2017)

Tags: c++, c

I'm learning C over the summer with the book "C Programming - A modern approach", now to the problem:

When I write:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

the compiler can't run the program because it can't include bool. When I use bool straight away it knows what it's supposed to do.

Is this something new in Visual Studio 2017 or do I start the documents wrong and get C# or C++? (I don't know those languages but I supposed boolean is well integrated in them)

I start my compiler by "Windows Desktop Wizard -> Empty project -> Source file -> Add -> New project -> C++ file (.cpp)"

It's not a huge problem (since it mostly makes things easier) but I want to learn C and not C++/C#.

Comment: The `.cpp` suffix is for C++, so you're programming in C++ and not C. And C++ have a `bool` type without needing the `<stdbool.h>` header file.

Comment: Why do you choose C++ file in the compiler? There's no C option?

Comment: C# is so much easier to learn. I admire you for going so low level but learning languages especially your first takes years. If you find C too hard give C# a try.

Comment: @JeremyThompson What you wrote is true, but .NET with its very large libraries makes many things seem like they are working "by magic". There is a very big abstraction that doesn't show you what your computer can do and how it can do it. Starting from C (with its "low level" feel) I fell you have better instruments to explore the inner working of .NET

Comment: @xanatos you're right. I wish I had the patience to learn C 20 yrs ago

Answer (score 2):

Give the (your) file the extension `.c`, not `.cpp`. In this way the Visual Studio will use the C language instead of using the C++ language. But note the response of Bathsheba... and a [so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615184/613130) that expands on what he wrote.

Comment: I would also set the project to 'compile as C'.

Comment: @Baldrick The default setting should be something akin "autosense". If I add a .c file and then write `bool test = true` I get errors both on `bool` and `true`... Some [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/tc-tp-tc-tp-specify-source-file-type) on this: *By default, CL assumes that files with the .c extension are C source files and files with the .cpp or the .cxx extension are C++ source files.*

Comment: Fair enough. I guess with the project compile setting you could probably force .cpp files to compile as C too. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Despite pretentions to the contrary, The C++ compiler that ships with Visual Studio is **not** a C compiler (it is in my opinion an excellent C++ compiler for targeting Windows). Even if you name a source file `.c` and are careful with the compiler settings it is still **not** a C compiler.

Your best bet here is to use a genuine C compiler if you want to write C programs; gcc in cygwin is a good toolset.