# Different errors on C , error C2275, C2146 and so on

Tags: c

i'm working on some project for now and took some snippets, and i face some problems, i don't know if smth wrong with code, but everything looks good and i can't understand where the problem is. I have already tried to fix it myself, but don't get how to do it. I know what each error mean. Need help
PS . this is a .h file , i checked out libraries and included everything, nothing helped.

```
SOCKET GetBackServerConnect(SOCKADDR_IN * pServerAddr, LPCSTR ClientId, DWORD ClientType, WORD * pBackPort, WORD * pUserPort, DWORD * pUnique)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;

    TInitialAnswer BuffRecv = { 0 };
    PInitialRequest BuffSend = BackVncGetInitialRequest(ClientId, ClientType);

    if (!BuffSend)
        return INVALID_SOCKET;

    SOCKET  ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET != ServerSocket)
    {
        if (0 == connect(ServerSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)pServerAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)))
        {
            DWORD dwOne = 1;
            if (0 == setsockopt(ServerSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (PCHAR)&dwOne, sizeof(dwOne)))
            {
                SetTimeout(ServerSocket, TimeoutExtendedMsec);

                if (BuffSend->size == send(ServerSocket, (PCHAR)BuffSend, BuffSend->size, 0))
                {
                    if (sizeof(BuffRecv) == recv(ServerSocket, (PCHAR)&BuffRecv, sizeof(BuffRecv), 0))
                    {
                        if (BackHelloOK == BuffRecv.status)
                        {
                            if (pBackPort)
                                *pBackPort = LOWORD(BuffRecv.backport);
                            if (pUserPort)
                                *pUserPort = LOWORD(BuffRecv.userport);
                            if (pUnique)
                                *pUnique = BuffRecv.unique;

                            ok = TRUE;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!ok)
    {
        shutdown(ServerSocket, SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(ServerSocket);
        ServerSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    hFree(BuffSend);
    return ServerSocket;
}
```

I face a few errors like :

```
1. error C2275: 'SOCKET' : illegal use of this type as an expression    

2. error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ServerSocket' - i dont understand it. 
3. error C2065: 'ServerSocket' : undeclared identifier
```

in this field :

```
SOCKET  ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)
```

and i also have a lot of `error C2065: 'ServerSocket' : undeclared identifier`  on the whole code where ServerSocket is. 
I have almost exact style code below with ClientSocket and never faced any problem with it...

Code from below UPDATE:
everything ok with this part of code, no errors, nothing, i don't understand

```
SOCKET GetBackClientConnect(SOCKADDR_IN * pServerAddr)
{
    BOOL ok = FALSE;

    SOCKET ClientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (INVALID_SOCKET != ClientSocket)
    {
        if (0 == connect(ClientSocket, (LPSOCKADDR)pServerAddr, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)))
        {
            DWORD dwOne = 1;
            if (0 == setsockopt(ClientSocket, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (PCHAR)&dwOne, sizeof(dwOne)))
            {
                SetTimeout(ClientSocket, TimeoutExtendedMsec);
                ok = TRUE;
            }
        }
    }

    if (!ok)
    {
        shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    return ClientSocket;
}
```

Comment: Is your compiler supporting variable definitions in the middle of the function?

Comment: it's a visual studio 2013

Comment: I don't have it to test. Write some little test program. MSVC is notorious for not respecting standards.

Comment: i will check it, i guess it supports c99 style and variable difinitions too

Comment: `SOCKET` is recognized by the compiler as a type, but it doesn't seem to like the fact that there's a variable definition is in the middle of the function. So put `SOCKET ServerSocket;` just after the definition of `BOOL ok`, then remove `SOCKET` from line 11, and recompile.

Comment: As i said above i have the exact same style code with variable difinition (updated the main post. look at it)

Comment: In the second snippet all of the definitions occur in the beginning of a block. So it  does not rule out our suspicion.

Comment: oh it help mate, thank you!! appreciate it, now i got it . i have some other file with similiar errors, will try to find it myself, and fix, if no i will return:) thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't be the same case with DWORD dwOne = 1?

Comment: @kiranBiradar It is in the beginning of the `if` block. So I would guess MSVC has nothing against it...

Comment: yeeaaah i just fixed my second errors haha, thank you, never thought it was so easy, But why is it happen? everything because of this variable difinition? really?

Comment: @Eugene Sh you cleared my daubt, thank you

Comment: It's pre-C99 thing. As I said, MSVC is not respecting modern standards

Comment: but i tried it with visual studio 2017 , and got everything the same...(

Comment: Even in 2017 C99 is not fully supported:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615184/does-visual-studio-2017-fully-support-c99

Comment: Does any version of MSVC have an option to permit mixed declarations and statements?

Comment: Repeat after me, MSVC is not a C compiler