# Is Visual Studio 2019 Compatible with C99?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2019, c99

I'm trying to build a C project from a public library I found on GitHub.  The header files are spitting out a ton of errors.  One of the obvious problems is that it doesn't recognized ellipses in macro definitions.  There are threads that indicate that the compatibility with C99 wasn't completely there in VS2017.

Anyone know what the current state of this is with Visual Studio 2019?  Is there some sort of flag that will give me C99 compatibility?

Comment: Also see [Does Visual Studio 2017 fully support C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48615184/2410359)

Comment: I suspect you are still (2020) out of luck with VS and full C99.  Consider using a C compiler other than one in VS.

Comment: C in VS mostly meets C89, I doubt it fully works with even C94/95 and certainly not all C99, C11 nor C17/18.  There is a trend here.  Time to move on.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica - It's not my code.

Comment: But it is your choice of compiler, that is what I am suggesting for you to change.

Comment: Anything on github meant for public consumption should have some build instructions.

Comment: You're talking about the preprocessor, variadic macros are supported.  The question is hopelessly vague without a repro snippet, arbitrary link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-experimental-overview?view=vs-2019

Comment: You could just compile your project with the C++ compiler instead of the C89 compiler. You might get a few warnings but it shouldn't be too much of an issue.