# Setting user defined array size

Tags: arrays, c

I'm writing a program and I've faced an issue where I cannot set the array size to the user's liking. I know it's a pointer-related issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int length;
    scanf_s("%d", &length);
    int array[length]; //"expression must have a constant value"
}
```

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: Read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67547489/453348, VS does not support C99

Comment: "I know it's a pointer-related issue." It is not, because there is no pointer involved in defining that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLAs are optional and MS compiler does not support them. You need to dynamically allocate the array:

```
int *array = malloc(length * sizeof(*array));
```

after use you need to `free` it manually

```
free(array);
```

Comment: *VLAs are optional...* Not under C99.  They must be supported for a compiler to be fully C99-compliant.  And it looks like a form of VLAs will also be required in C2X, which will probably wind being called C23.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `(Variable length arrays are a conditional feature that implementations need not support; see
6.10.8.3.)` C17

Comment: @AndrewHenle `__STDC_NO_VLA__ The integer constant 1, intended to indicate that the implementation does not
support variable length arrays or variably modified types.` C17

Comment: And all that contradicts "Not under C99" in what way?  Depending on the standard compiled under, VLAs can very well be mandatory.