# Which version of C is supported by VS2019 compiler?

Tags: c, visual-studio, version

How can I know which version of C is supported by the VS2019 compiler? I looked in the project C/C++ and Linker command lines and found no -std=Cxx flag. The following code compiles:

```
for (int i = index; i < nb_users - 1; i++) {
    users[i] = users[i + 1];
}
```

So I *guess* it's C99 according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287863/c-for-loop-int-initial-declaration), but is there a way to check this somewhere in VS2019?

Comment: C89 plus a few bits and pieces of later standards.

Comment: What does `printf("%ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);` report?

Comment: @chux It does not compile, "identifier is undefined". Sorry I'm new in C as you can tell.

Comment: `__STDC_VERSION__` wasn't allowed in C90, nor was declaring a variable inside a for loop `for (int i =...`. If you are a newbie, you are much better off throwing VS in the garbage and get a standard C compiler. For example Codeblocks with gcc/mingw compiler, it is a reasonably newbie-friendly Windows toolchain.

Comment: @supafly *It does not compile...* That means VS2019 is not a [C99-compliant compiler](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.10.8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS2019 supports ANSI C90 plus a few other features from a few later standards that are required in C++.

For example, you can tell that C99 is not fully supported in MSVC with this code, which will fail to compile:

```
int foo(int n, char *s)
{
    char s2[n];
    strcpy(s2, s);
    return !strcmp(s, s2);
}
```

This specific feature (variable-length arrays) is not supported in MSVC, while the feature you mentioned (`for` loop initial declaration) is.

Answer (score 1):

> Which version of C is supported by VS2019 compiler?

At best, C 1989.

---

A compliant compiler to some C standard is identifiable via the values of `__STDC__` `__STDC_VERSION__`.

```
#ifndef __STDC__
  printf("Does not ID itself as compliant to any C standard.\n");
#else
  printf("Compliant to some C standard\n");
  #ifndef __STDC_VERSION__
    printf("C 1989\n");
  #else 
    // Expected values of of 2019
    // 199409L
    // 199901L
    // 201112L
    // 201710L
    printf("C %ld\n", __STDC_VERSION__);
  #endif
#endif
```

I'd expect VS2019 to not identify itself compliant to any C standard or perhaps 1989.

> **__STDC__** Defined as 1 only when compiled as C and if the [/Za](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=vs-2019) compiler option is specified. Otherwise, undefined.  [Predefined macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=vs-2019)

---

VS2019 not on this [*incomplete* list of C compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_compilers#C_compilers)

Comment: Indeed, it does not identify itself compliant to any C standard. The `/Za` link in your answer is helpful.

Comment: Should it be `#elif __STDC__ == 1 printf("Compliant ...");` instead of `#else printf("Compliant ...");`?

Comment: @pmor Maybe after the `#ifndef __STDC__   printf("Does ...` could as `#elif __STDC__ != 1 printf("Not Compliant");` for a pedantic test - and then go on to the `#else
  printf("Compliant to some C standard\n");`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `__STDC__` is defined using "positive logic". Hence, I find logical to use "positive logic" as well: `#if __STDC__ == 1 /* compliant */ #else /* not defined OR defined to != 1 => not compliant */ #endif`.