# Why is const int x = 5; not a constant expression in C?

Tags: c, constants, visual-studio-2019, c99, variable-length-array

I thought C had no more surprises for me, but this surprised me.

```
    const int NUM_FOO = 5;
    ....

    int foo[NUM_FOO];
==>error C2057: expected constant expression
```

My C++ experience has made me internally deprecate `#define` as much as possible. So this one was a real surprise. VS2019, compiled with /TC. I thought C99 allowed variable size arrays anyway.

1. Can anybody explain why the rejection occurs, since the compiler for sure knows at compile time the size of the array?
2. Is it not the case that C99 allows variable size arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `const` in C does not declare a compile-time constant.  You can use an `enum` constant instead if you want to avoid using `#define` and want a symbolic name that can appear in a debugger.
2. C99 *does* support VLAs.  However, [VS2019 does not support C99.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965155/which-version-of-c-is-supported-by-vs2019-compiler)

Answer (score 7):

In C, this declaration:

```
const int NUM_FOO = 5;
```

doesn't make `NUM_FOO` a constant expression.

The thing to remember (and yes, this is a bit counterintuitive) is that `const` doesn't mean *constant*. A *constant expression* is, roughly, one that can be evaluated at compile time (like `2+2` or `42`). The `const` type qualifier, even though its name is obviously derived from the English word "constant", really means "read-only".

Consider, for example, that these are a perfectly valid declarations:

```
const int r = rand();
const time_t now = time(NULL);
```

The `const` just means that you can't modify the value of `r` or `now` after they've been initialized. Those values clearly cannot be determined until execution time.

(C++ has different rules. It does make `NUM_FOO` a constant expression, and a later version of the language added `constexpr` for that purpose. C++ is not C.)

As for variable length arrays, yes, C added them in C99 (and made them optional in C11). But as [jamesdlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62354222/827263) pointed out, VS2019 doesn't support C99 or C11.

(C++ doesn't support VLAs. This: `const int NUM_FOO = 5; int foo[NUM_FOO];` is legal in both C99 and C++, but for different reasons.)

If you want to define a named constant of type `int`, you can use an `enum`:

```
enum { NUM_FOO = 5 };
```

or an old-fashioned macro (which isn't restricted to type `int`):

```
#define NUM_FOO 5
```

[jamesdlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62354222/827263) and [dbush's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62354229/827263) are both correct. I'm just adding a bit more context.

Answer (score 3):

A variable with the `const` qualifier does not qualify as a constant expression.

Section 6.6p6 of the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding Constant Expressions states

> An *integer constant  expression* shall  have  integer  type  and 
>   shall  only  have  operands that   are   integer   constants,
>   enumeration   constants,   character   constants, `sizeof` expressions
>   whose  results  are  integer  constants, `_Alignof` expressions,  and 
>   floating constants that are the immediate operands of casts.  Cast
>   operators in an integer constant expression  shall  only  convert 
>   arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,  except  as  part  of  an
>   operand to the `sizeof` or `_Alignof` operator

Note that `const` qualified integer objects are not included.

This means that `int foo[NUM_FOO];` is a variable length array, defined as follows from section 6.7.6.2p4:

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type.  If
>   the size is `*` instead of being  an  expression,  the  array  type 
>   is  a *variable  length  array* type  of  unspecified  size, which can
>   only be used in declarations or type names with function prototype
>   scope; such arrays are nonetheless complete types.  **If the size is
>   an integer constant expression and  the  element  type  has  a  known 
>   constant  size,  the  array  type  is  not  a  variable  length array 
>   type;**  otherwise,  the  array  type  is  a variable  length  array
>   type.

As for the error you're getting, that is because Visual Studio is not fully compliant with C99 and does not support variable length arrays.

Answer (score 1):

On top of the existing answers which are all good, the reason a `const`-qualified object fundamentally can't in general be a constant expression, in the sense of "one that can be evaluated at compile time" (as mentioned in Keith's answer), is that it can have *external linkage*. For example, you can have in `foo.c`

```
const int NUM_FOO = 5;
```

and in `bar.c`:

```
extern int NUM_FOO;
...
int foo[NUM_FOO];
```

In this example, the value of `NUM_FOO` cannot be known when compiling `bar.c`; it is not known until you choose to link `foo.o` and `bar.o`.

C's model of "constant expression" is closely tied to properties that allow translation units (source files) to be translated (compiled) independently to a form that requires no further high-level transformations to link. This is also why you can't use addresses in constant expressions except for address constant expressions which are limited to essentially the address of an object plus a constant.

Comment: True (but C++ does allow this when the initial value is visible; I'm not sure of the exact rules).