# Variable length arrays showing not defined in Clion Debugger (Mac OS Big Sur)

Tags: macos, clion

int main() {

```
 int n;
 cin>>n;
 int a[n+5];
 for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
     cin>>a[i];
 }
 return 0;
```

}

The array named "a" is not showing in the debugger window. But if I change the declaration to  "int a[100]" , its working.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65429354/10470363).  VLAs are not supported in the compiler you're using.

Comment: It compiles without any problem. The issue is with debugger , whenever I try to check the array in variables tab , it wont show up.