# What to do with *.h.cmake file

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, mingw, sox

I'm trying to build [pysox](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysox) (module to use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/Main/HomePage) in Python). But mingw32-gcc show the error: "soxstdint.h: No such file". The SoX source code doesn't distribute a "soxstdint.h", only a "soxstdint.h.cmake". What do I have to do with it? I couldn't figure out whether [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) can help me.

I need to get "soxstdint.h". Fine, if somebody can tell me some background information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just downloaded the pysox 0.3.6.alpha source from the [link you provided](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysox#downloads), and the string soxstdint does not appear in any of its files. Along the same lines, there is no soxstdint.h.cmake file either. Where did you get your source? BTW, I also downloaded [SoX 14.4.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sox/files/sox/14.4.0/) and it also does not include the string soxstdint.

That being said, stdint.h, is a standard C library file, and it is #included by several files in the sox and pysox distributions I downloaded. Now stdint.h was [not until recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio) included with Visual Studio, so perhaps the SoX people created a custom version as a workaround, and since you are on Windows, it is being looked for, but since it is MinGW and not Visual Studio, the workaround is failing.

I recommend downloading the latest pysox and sox source or a prebuilt binary package, if such things are available for MinGW. If you already have, then there is likely a small bug in SoX's CMakeLists.txt files that is perhaps concatenating "sox" and "stdint.h" without a slash (/) or other important character separating them. If that fails, I think you need to appeal to the SoX and PySoX developers. They should be interested in seeing their code work on platforms like MinGW.

Comment: Thanks for checking that. They removed it. I used that version, which was said to be compatible with pysox.