# Do I need an "so" file or what's wrong?

Tags: c, build, mingw, ld

(I'm on Windows.)

I try to build [pysox](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysox). Therefore I built libsox (part of [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)). It is said, that pysox needs "libsox.so and libsox.a in your link path." When building libsox I got "libsox.a", "libsox-1.dll", "libsox.dll.a", "libsox.la", "libsox.lai" and many other strange files. When I placed "libsox.a" in my link path, the previously shown error disappeared. But now the build script has an error when it calls mingw32-gcc which says:

```
C:\Programme\MinGW\bin\mingw32-gcc.exe -shared -s build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pysox\sox.o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pysox\sox.def -LC:\Programme\Python\libs -LC:\Programme\Python\PCbuild -lsox -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\pysox\sox.pyd
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pysox\sox.o:sox.c:(.text+0x3a96): undefined reference to `sox_get_encodings_info'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pysox\sox.o:sox.c:(.text+0x5035): undefined reference to `sox_get_encodings_info'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pysox\sox.o:sox.c:(.text+0x795d): undefined reference to `bcopy'
build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\pysox\sox.o:sox.c:(.text+0xa8b3): undefined reference to `bcopy'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'mingw32-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

The following attempts didn't work:

- Placing "libsox-1.dll" in link path
- Renaming it to "libsox.dll"
- Renaming it to "libsox.so"
- Placing all files generated along with "libsox.a" in link path

Do I really need an "so" file on Windows (how do I get it)? Or what has to be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MinGW uses a static interface library for each dynamic link library (DLL). The libsox.dll.a library is the one you need at link time, i.e. that needs to be copied into the link path. libsox-1.dll is required in the PATH at runtime, but not needed at link time.

You don't need a .so file on Windows platforms. It seems that some symbols are missing from the static library libsox.a, or that a library is missing from the link line. Windows platforms do not allow unresolved symbols in DLLs, contrary to UNIX-like .so platforms. You might have to give the library containing `sox_get_encodings_info` and friends explicitly on the command line, remembering precedence on the linker line.

Comment: I replaced "libsox.a" with "libsox.dll.a" in Python's libs directory. But the errors remain.

Comment: @rynd: Where is the `sox_get_encodings_info` symbol defined?

Comment: I used a newer version of sox.h which I had to copy to the Python include directory. The name sox_encodings_info was changed to sox_get_encodings_info in the newer version. So now I have an old problem again, which was resolved in the new version of sox.h and that I described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162636/what-to-do-with-h-cmake-file .

Comment: I tried to build sox-14.4.0 and sox-14.3.2 instead of sox-14.3.0 now, but there's was the next error of the next kind. My antivirus stated "conftest.exe" as malware, which is created while running the configure script. I set an exception for it and I was able to compile it.