# detect 64-bit integer type without preprocessor or stdint.h

Tags: c++, c++11

Without using `#if`, `stdint.h`, `inttypes.h`, or compiler-specific extensions (other than nonstandard intrinsic types), but making free use of all other C++ features (including C++11 `type_traits` for instance) is it possible to write code that has the effect of

```
typedef {some implementation-specific type} int_least64;
```

if and only if there is an implementation-specific type that provides at least 64 bits of precision, and otherwise produces a compile-time error?

The construct should detect nonstandard intrinsic types that might have the desired properties (e.g. `__int64` on MSVC++) as well as standard ones (`long`, `long long`).  If several types fit the requirement it should pick the smallest one that qualifies.  Ideally it would be generalizable to use in `enable_if` as well as just erroring out, and to detect arbitrarily large integers (e.g. some compilers provide `__int128` now).

Comment: Why would you not just use <cstdint>?

Comment: What do you mean by "detect"?  Does this include types that you aren't aware of?  C++ doesn't support reflection.

Comment: This isn't possible or desirable.

Comment: I would not use `cstdint` because AFAIK MSVC *still* does not have it (even in the latest version with the spiffy C++11 features).  Yes, this is meant to include types I, the programmer, am not aware of, if at all possible.  And I'd like to know why @SethCarnegie thinks this is not *desirable*.

Comment: @Zack according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio MSVC 2010 has `cstdint`.

Comment: @ecatmur Without further information I have to consider that unreliable.  (I found a page on MSDN that confirms that the header *exists* but does not say anything about what it *contains*, leading me to believe that this is yet another Microsoft attempt to comply with the letter of a standard without actually making it *usable*.  Feh.)

Comment: `long long` is at least 64 bits and provided by all current compilers. What is wrong with using that?

Comment: @Zack it's not desirable to waste time trying to do something this ethereal and impossible.

Comment: @Zack if you don't trust the header, write your own or use `#ifdef`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/127166/567292

Comment: @ecatmur In real life I am, in fact, using `#if`; the question is meant to probe what is *possible*.

Comment: @BoPersson That's another thing I was under the impression MSVC++ did not support.  (Basically I assume anything that was in C99 but not C++98 doesn't work on Windows unless I have really hard evidence to the contrary.)

Comment: @Zack - They do (unless you use VC6 or something :-). Even though they have their own `__int64`, that is just treated as a (kind of) typedef for `long long`. C99 is not supported, but some extensions to C++98 have been there for quite some time.

Comment: What's the best way to pound in a nail without using a hammer?

Comment: @Zack: Perhaps in the future, you could try looking things up rather than assuming them. VC++ Express is a free download; just check the include directory.

Comment: I'm baffled by the hostility here.  What's wrong with asking a question about things that may now have a better way to accomplish them?  C++11 added a ton of new stuff, it was _conceivable_ that there was novel introspection on types.

Comment: @Zack: "*What's wrong with asking a question about things that may now have a better way to accomplish them?*" Because it involves not bothering to do any research. You assume that VS2010 doesn't have `<cstdint>` when it does and would have taken a few seconds to check on your own (assuming you have it installed). And while C++11 added "a ton of new stuff", that "ton" has been carefully itemized on Wikipedia. Type introspection isn't on the list. Also, a feature to "detect" whether the compiler has some feature is pretty much a non-starter as far as standardization goes.

Comment: I suppose lengthy bitter experience with (a) the things MSVC++ *claims* to support that don't actually work, or that are implemented in a way that is technically standard compliant but useless for anyone trying to write portable code, and (b) the sheer variety of clever tricks that can be pulled in C++ that are not apparent from the bare descriptions of the features they use, or even the text of the standard; could look like not doing one's own research, from a sufficient distance. I don't care what you think of me, but you should consider the consequences of making it not fun to be here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.  There are no facilities for a program to introspect the types available from the implementation, and given an unqualified name there is no way to use it in a program in such a way that the program continues to be well-formed even if the name does not denote a type.

That was part of the motivation for adding `cstdint` to C++, along with C99 compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is MSVC and `<cstdint>`, upgrade to at least MSVS2010 or write it yourself for Windows. It's not hard.

There is some template trickery you can use, but it still requires `long long` to get up (and over) 64-bits integers.

I got it from a guy in the SO C++ Lounge (namely @StackedCrooked):

https://github.com/rubenvb/KISS/blob/master/include/types.hxx#L47

Comment: Or just use the one that's been provided with [Boost.Integer](http://www.boost.org/libs/integer/) for years.