# How to guarantee long is 4 bytes

Tags: c++, g++

In c++, is there any way to guarantee that a long is 4 bytes? Perhaps a compiler flag for g++?

We are reusing some windows code in a linux program, and in windows a long is 4 bytes, but on my linux machine a long is 8 bytes. We can't go and change all the longs to ints because that would break the windows code.

The reason I need to guarantee longs are 4 bytes is because in certain parts of the code, we have a union of a struct and a char array, and when compiling for 64bit linux, the char array does not line up with the other struct.

Here are some code snippits for clarification:

```
struct ABC {
    unsigned long  data1;
    unsigned short data2;
    unsigned short data3;
    unsigned char  data4[8];
};
//sizeof(ABC) (32 bit): 16, sizeof(ABC) (64 bit): 24

union ABC_U {
    ABC abc;
    unsigned char bytes[16];
};
```

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, this problem only came up when trying to compile for 64 bit. Windows seems to like to keep longs 4 bytes regardless of architecture, whereas linux g++ usually makes longs the same size as pointers.

I'm leaning towards using a uint32_t here because this particular structure isn't used in the Windows code, and that wouldn't affect the program globally. Hopefully there aren't any other sections of the code where this will be a problem.

I found the compiler flag -mlong32, but this also forces pointers to be 32 bits which is undesirable, and as it forces nonstandard behavior would likely break the ABI like PascalCuoq mentioned.

Comment: How about specifying the integer size in bits, like uint64?

Comment: @user2613971: Or `uint64_t`, which has the virtue of being standard -- though it looks like the OP is looking for `int32_t`.

Comment: To support such a switch, your implementation would need to ship an alternate Standard Library compiled with `sizeof(long)==4`. But this does not scale: if you have N such options, you need to ship 2^N Standard Library implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `int` and `long`, you will likely want to create a header file that uses typedef's (preferred) or preprocessor macros to define common typenames for you to use.

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS
typedef unsigned long uint32;
#else
typedef unsigned int uint32;
#endif
```

In your union, you would use `uint32` instead of `long`.

The header file `stdint.h` does exactly this, but is not always installed as a standard header file with every compiler.  Visual Studio (for example) does not have it by default.  You can download it from http://msinttypes.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/stdint.h if you would prefer to use it instead.

Comment: Visual Studio *does* have it by default.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I believe a recent version does but that is new.

Comment: @Benjamin:  That depends on which version of VS you are using.

Comment: Well it's had it since 2010 (before it was part of the C++ standard), and if you say "Visual Studio does not have it", in the present tense, without a version qualification, I think it's only reasonable to assume you are referring to the most recent commercially available edition.

Comment: It only had it after you installed the service patch (SP2 if I remember correctly).  It was not installed with the original 2010 release.  The point was that it may or may not be installed, so you can download it (if you wish to use it), or write your own.

Answer (score 4):

You can use int32_t from stdint.h.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this header doesn't exist on windows below a certain visual studio version (2010?)

Comment: @cppguy: So roll your own.

Comment: Isn't that his problem to begin with? He's trying to make sure he has a typedef that's correct?

Comment: You can look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio to get stdint.h for visual studio.

Comment: While correct, this is not a complete answer.  See my answer below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You want the compiler to generate code where `long` is 32-bit.

Compile the entire codebase with `-m32`. This will generate code in the old IA-32 instruction set, which is still widely supported library-wise(*), and where `long` is traditionally 32-bit like `int`.

(*) You may need to install these libraries in your Linux distribution, and you may have to ask your users to install them.

Comment: The problem with this is that we are using the rpm library, and if a 32 bit program uses this library on a 64 bit machine, the rpm database tends to get corrupted, and it becomes a hassle to use programs that access these databases, like yum.

Comment: @BrianSchlenker Well even if it was possible to force `long` to be 32-bit through an option while generating x86-64 code, it would break the ABI and prevent linking with **any** library, including but not limited to rpm. So the answer to your question augmented with this information is “no, there is no way to force a long to be 4 bytes”.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Seems like the only way will be to change the type from long to something else and hopefully not break any of the Windows code.