# no stdint.h in Visual Studio 2005, cannot compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to compile the format.h and format.cc classes found here:

https://github.com/vitaut/format

I can compile the files no problem on Visual Studio 2010, but 2005 will not compile due to a missing stdint.h class.  If I write a wrapper and compile the class into a static library in Visual Studio 2010, would I run into any issues compiling / linking and ultimately executing with it in Visual Studio 2005?  I would think no...

Comment: You could also make your own stdint.h

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

Thanks deviant fan for the link.  That sounds like the best approach.  It turns out that the code posted here:

[C++ performance challenge: integer to std::string conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351371/c-performance-challenge-integer-to-stdstring-conversion)

by user434507 is actually faster for my case than the format library referenced above.  So I'm simply going to use that instead.