# Creating bmp file in C

Tags: c, bmp

I am trying to create .bmp file (filled with one colour for testing purposes).

Here is code that I'm using:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BI_RGB 0

typedef unsigned int UINT;
typedef unsigned long DWORD;
typedef long int LONG;
typedef unsigned short WORD;
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    UINT bfType;
    DWORD bfSize;
    UINT bfReserved1;
    UINT bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

typedef struct tagBITMAPINFOHEADER {
    DWORD biSize;
    LONG biWidth;
    LONG biHeight;
    WORD biPlanes;
    WORD biBitCount;
    DWORD biCompression;
    DWORD biSizeImage;
    LONG biXPelsPerMeter;
    LONG biYPelsPerMeter;
    DWORD biClrUsed;
    DWORD biClrImportant;
} BITMAPINFOHEADER;

typedef struct COLORREF_RGB
{
    BYTE cRed;
    BYTE cGreen;
    BYTE cBlue;
}COLORREF_RGB;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    BITMAPINFOHEADER bih;

    bih.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bih.biWidth = 600;
    bih.biHeight = 600;
    bih.biSizeImage = bih.biWidth * bih.biHeight * 3;
    bih.biPlanes = 1;
    bih.biBitCount = 24;
    bih.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bih.biXPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bih.biYPelsPerMeter = 2835;
    bih.biClrUsed = 0;
    bih.biClrImportant = 0;



    COLORREF_RGB rgb;
    rgb.cRed = 0;
    rgb.cGreen = 0;
    rgb.cBlue = 0;



    BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;

    bfh.bfType = 0x424D;
    bfh.bfReserved1 = 0;
    bfh.bfReserved2 = 0;
    bfh.bfOffBits = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + bih.biSize;
    bfh.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) +
        bih.biWidth * bih.biHeight * 4;


    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("test.bmp","wb");
    fwrite(&bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f);
    fwrite(&bih, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, f);

    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < bih.biHeight; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < bih.biWidth; j++)
        {
            fwrite(&rgb,sizeof(COLORREF_RGB),1,f);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);

    return 0;
}
```

and jet every time I compile and run it I get error saying that its not valid BMP image. I double checked all values in multiple references and still can't find error here.

Did I misunderstood something and what am I doing wrong here?

Also not sure if important but I am using Ubuntu 14.04 to compile this.

*EDIT*

Found one more issue :

```
bfh.bfType = 0x424D;
```

should be

```
bfh.bfType = 0x4D42;
```

But still can't see image.

Comment: Looks like a struct member alignment issue here. What happens if you put `#pragma pack(1)` just before declaring the structs ?

Comment: Now I got "Error reading BMP file header from ..."

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct ordering of bytes for multi-byte values

Comment: The error you are quoting cannot possibly occur in the code you pasted in your question. How did you get it ?

Comment: I copy/pasted code from above, compiled and runed it, and tried to open image with GIMP.

Comment: you need to (using an appropriate editor) examine the contents of the output file.  to assure it exactly matches the format listed at: <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format> which fully defines the BMP format and has this statement: " All of the integer values are stored in little-endian format (i.e. least-significant byte first)."

Comment: typedef unsigned int UINT is most likely a different size on 64bit compared to 32bit.

Comment: this link (and the related links found at the bottom of the page) will tell you everything you ever wanted to know about BMP file formats/contents <http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183376%28v=vs.85%29.aspx>

Comment: this link: <http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/Cpp/BitmapTutorial.html> contains a very clear tutorial on how to load/save BMP images, using the windows API. (which assumes the underlying hardware is little endian, so you may have to tweak the method of setting some values so they are saved in the correct format (I.E. byte at a time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your field sizes to be incorrect, try this

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)

typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
    WORD bfType;
    DWORD bfSize;
    WORD bfReserved1;
    WORD bfReserved2;
    DWORD bfOffBits;
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

Comment: Its still same. I am using [this](http://www.digicamsoft.com/bmp/bmp.html) as my main ref and they say that it should be `unsigned int`.

Comment: It does not say `unsigned int` it says `UINT` And where on that page is `UINT` defined? I don't care what your page says, I compiled and ran your program with the alterations commented here and it creates a 600x600 black 24-bit bitmap that my image viewer displays.

Comment: Did you include the `pack` pragmas that @SirDarius recommended in the very first comment (which I added to my answer after your recent comment)?

Comment: Weird thing, but I just compiled it on my windows PC and it worked there. As I mentioned in post I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Defining a portable file format with machine-specific field sizes is a no-no, see comment from @Matt.

Comment: Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: define all fields as char name[size]  then fill the field byte by byte.  then there is no problem with alignment bytes, etc

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you set:

> `bfSize`          Specifies the size of the file, in bytes.

to invalid value, your code resulted into `1440112` while size of file is actually `1080112`

```
bfh.bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) +
    bih.biWidth * bih.biHeight * sizeof(COLORREF_RGB);
```

Because `sizeof(COLORREF_RGB)` is actually 4 not 3.

Another mistake is that size of your structs and types:

```
                                  expected size        actual size*
typedef unsigned int UINT;    //              2                  4
typedef unsigned long DWORD;  //              4                  8
typedef long int LONG;        //              4                  8
typedef unsigned short WORD;  //              2                  2
typedef unsigned char BYTE;   //              1                  1
```

<sub>* I'm using gcc on x86_64 architecture</sub>

Your offsets just don't match with offsets on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header), reference you are using was probably written for 16 bit compiler on 16 bit OS (as pointed out by [cup in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27215610/creating-bmp-file-in-c/27217045?noredirect=1#comment42914021_27217045)) so it assumes `int` to be 2B type.

Using values from `stdint.h` worked for me (guide on `stdint.h` for Visual Studio [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/126279/1149736)):

```
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint16_t UINT;
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef int32_t LONG;
typedef uint16_t WORD;
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
```

And last but not least you have to turn off memory alignment as [suggested by Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27216493/1149736).

Comment: Just as a side note: bmp was a format used by 16-bit windows which is why UINT is uint16_t.  On the 16 bit compilers, int was 16 bits.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to map a C structure to some externally-defined binary format  There are a number of problems with this:

#### Size

> ```
> typedef unsigned int UINT;
> typedef unsigned long DWORD;
> typedef long int LONG;
> typedef unsigned short WORD;
> typedef unsigned char BYTE;
> ```

The C language only specify the *minimum* sizes of these types. Their actual sizes can and do vary between different compilers and operating systems. The sizes and offset of the members in your structures may not be what you expect. The only size that you can rely on (on *almost* any system that you are likely to encounter these days) is `char` being 8 bits.

#### Padding

> ```
> typedef struct tagBITMAPFILEHEADER {
>     UINT bfType;
>     DWORD bfSize;
>     UINT bfReserved1;
>     UINT bfReserved2;
>     DWORD bfOffBits;
> } BITMAPFILEHEADER;
> ```

It is common for `DWORD` to be twice as large as a `UINT`, and in fact your program depends on it. This usually means that the compiler will introduce padding between `bfType` and `bfSize` to give the latter appropriate alignment for its type. The [`.bmp` format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) has no such padding.

#### Order

> ```
> BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh;
>
> bfh.bfType = 0x424D;
> ...
> fwrite(&bfh, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, f);
> ```

Another problem is that the C language does not specify the *endianess* of the types. The `.bfType` member may be stored as `[42][4D]` (Big-Endian) or `[4D][42]` (Little-Endian) in memory. The [`.bmp` format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) specifically requires the values to be stored in Little-Endian order.

#### Solution

You *might* be able to solve *some* of these problems by using compiler-specific extensions (such as `#pragma`'s or compiler switches), but probably not all of them.

The only way to properly write an externally-defined binary format, is to use an array of `unsigned char` and write the values a byte at a time. Personally, I would write a set of helper functions for specific types:

```
void w32BE (unsigned char *p, unsigned long ul)
{
  p[0] = (ul >> 24) & 0xff;
  p[1] = (ul >> 16) & 0xff;
  p[2] = (ul >>  8) & 0xff;
  p[3] = (ul      ) & 0xff;
}
void w32LE (unsigned char *p, unsigned long ul)
{
  p[0] = (ul      ) & 0xff;
  p[1] = (ul >>  8) & 0xff;
  p[2] = (ul >> 16) & 0xff;
  p[3] = (ul >> 24) & 0xff;
}
/* And so on */
```

and some functions for writing the entire `.bmp` file or sections of it:

```
int function write_header (FILE *f, BITMAPFILEHEADER bfh)
{
  unsigned char buf[14];

  w16LE (buf   , bfh.bfType);
  w32LE (buf+ 2, bfh.bfSize);
  w16LE (buf+ 6, bfh.bfReserved1);
  w16LE (buf+ 8, bfh.bfReserved2);
  w32LE (buf+10, bfh.bfOffBits);

  return fwrite (buf, sizeof buf, 1, f);
}
```