# Windows compilation failure on pip install due to invalid command flags

Tags: python, c++, pip, lz4

I was trying to install the lz4 package on my Windows machine from PyPi using pip.  This package doesn't have any wheels uploaded so it was going to need to compile the source locally.  I have the Visual C++ for Python compiler installed.

I ran:

```
pip install lz4
```

This gave me a compilation error:

```
C:\Users\Nick\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ic:\Python27\include -Ic:\Python27\PC /Tcsrc/lz4.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src/lz4.obj -std=c99 -O3 -Wall -W -Wundef -DLZ4_VERSION="r119"
cl : Command line error D8004 : '/W' requires an argument
```

On downloading the tar file from PyPi I could see that the **-W** and **-Wundef** compiler arguments were being set explicitly, but these are not legal flags for the MSVC compiler.

```
    ext_modules=[
    Extension('lz4', [
        'src/lz4.c',
        'src/lz4hc.c',
        'src/python-lz4.c'
    ], extra_compile_args=[
        "-std=c99",
        "-O3",
        "-Wall",
        "-W",
        "-Wundef",
        "-DLZ4_VERSION=\"r119\"",
    ])
```

I removed these from my local copy of the source and ran setup against the modified code.

```
python setup.py install
```

I still had a problem with stdint.h being missing, discussed [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio), but after solving that the install succeeded.

My questions are:

- Am I missing something here, is there something wrong with my set-up that meant the build was failing?
- Is there a way to specify command arguments in setup.py in a platform specific way?
- I can see on the [lz4 PyPi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lz4/0.7.0) that the build is passing.  What does this actually mean?

Comment: For the 1st and 3rd questions: 1) flags are meant for gcc, not MSVC. 3) either the project is build-tested only on Linux and/or it is also build on Windows but with a gcc port. In both cases the build is probably passing the same way. You could try to raise attention on this problem in the project issue tracker.